# Document template connects to the wrong tenant/term store - sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, word, document-template

I have a word document template connected to a document content type that exists in two deployment environments (tenants) in SharePoint online.

If I create a document using my account that has been in both environments and choose to edit the document in desktop-word, the quick part metadata always shows entries from environment A, regardless of from which environment I create the document.

However, if I log in on different computers, and only authenticating to one environment, everything works as expected.

I suspect that desktop-word is storing credentials somewhere, but I have tried emptying the account list and all credentials in the windows credential manager to no avail.

Are there other places that desktop word stores credentials, or am I missing something else?

Answer (score 0):

Solved by deleting

c:\user\USERNAME\appdata\local\microsoft\office\termstores